# Integrate files and directories form one part of a directory tree controlled by git to another

Tags: git

I have a directory tree all controlled by git.  In one part of the tree say `.../project/master_scripts`  I have a set of master scripts that I use for work on a project.

In another part of the tree I have the locations where the users do the work and will use these scripts and potentially make changes.

```
.../project/work/users/me/scripts
```

I would like to "integrate" the scripts from `master_scripts/...` to `.../me/scripts`  then be able to edit and make changes in `.../me/scripts` for my specific use.  I would still like to maintain the link back to the master scripts so that I can check, be notified and merge any changes from the master scripts into my user version.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check out [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). These scripts would be in their own version controlled repository and can be configured to be installed into whatever directory you would like.

Then, anytime an update is made to the scripts, you can update in your super project and the changes will be made to your submodule project.